# A c++20 range adaptor whose produced values are iterators to the underlying range

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, range-based-loop

I want to have the following work

```
std::vector<int> range{0,1,2,3};

for(std::vector<int>::iterator vit : range | iterator_range  ){
   int v = *vit;
}
```

this would be equivalent to the standard for loop

```
std::vector<int> range{0,1,2,3};

for(std::vector<int>::iterator vit = begin(range); vit !=end(range); vit++)  ){
   int v = *vit;
}
```

except more elegant.

`iterator_range` is an adapter that I require.

I have some algorithms where it is useful to require to have an iterator to the element inside the loop rather than the element itself.

Comment: C++ ranges have been introduced to provide a higher-level abstraction over some collection of data. They are about working with preprocessed elements rather than with iterators pointing to elements. If I were you I'd rather go for proper usage of ranges or focus on iterators and iterator adapters if needed.

Comment: I'm very well aware of what they were designed to do. My question stands. The standards supplied https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view which is very close to what I want. Rather than the index I'd prefer to have the iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `views::iota` is not limited to integers, it's anything that's incrementable and comparable. Which includes iterators!

```cpp
inline constexpr auto iterators_of = []<ranges::range R>(R&& r){
    static_assert(ranges::borrowed_range<R>);
    return views::iota(ranges::begin(r), ranges::end(r));
};
```

This at least gets you started, and maybe is good enough. Ideally you have a proper range adapter that captures `views::all(r)` without requiring borrowed, and actually gives out these iterators directly.

A more complete implementation (if actually necessary) would be:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::view V>
struct iterators_for_view : std::ranges::view_interface<iterators_for_view<V>> {
    V view;

    template <class R>
    using iota_for = std::ranges::iota_view<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>, std::ranges::sentinel_t<R>>;

    explicit iterators_for_view(V v) : view(std::move(v)) { }

    auto begin() { return std::ranges::iterator_t<iota_for<V>>(std::ranges::begin(view)); }
    auto end() { return std::ranges::sentinel_t<iota_for<V>>(std::ranges::end(view)); }

    auto begin() const requires std::ranges::range<V const> { return std::ranges::iterator_t<iota_for<V const>>(std::ranges::begin(view)); }
    auto end() const requires std::ranges::range<V const> { return std::ranges::sentinel_t<iota_for<V const>>(std::ranges::end(view)); }    

    auto size() requires std::ranges::sized_range<V> { return std::ranges::size(view); }
    auto size() const requires std::ranges::sized_range<V const> { return std::ranges::size(view); }
};

struct iterators_for_fn : std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure<iterators_for_fn> {
    template <std::ranges::viewable_range R>
    constexpr auto operator()(R&& r) const {
        return iterators_for_view(std::views::all((R&&)r));
    }
};

inline constexpr iterators_for_fn iterators_for{};
```

Which you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8TM1WYYMs).

Answer (score 3):

Iterator types always satisfy `weakly_incrementable`, so you can use `iota_view`:

```
std::vector<int> range{0,1,2,3};
auto make_iter_range = [](std::ranges::range auto&& r) {
  return std::views::iota(std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r));
};
for (auto vit : make_iter_range(range)) {
  int v = *vit;
}
```